# Como Continuar envio de formulário após "e.preventDefault();"

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um código de uma barra de pesquisa animada, porém a animação não funciona junto com o envio da pesquisa. Acredito que seja o "e.preventDefault();" que não estou conseguindo trazer o evento depois após a animação:

```
<form action='/search' method='get'>
<input id="search" type="search" name="q" />
<p></p>
</form>
<script>
var form = $('form'),
search = $('#search');

form.submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

search.addClass('searching').val('');

setTimeout(function() {
    search.removeClass('searching');
}, 3600);
event.currentTarget.submit(); // Com essa linha consigo enviar mas a pesquisa digitada não vai
});

    </script>
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: O formulário funciona perfeitamente sem esse script, mas ao adiciona-lo a animação flui corretamente mas as pesquisas param de funcionar:
    <script>
    var form = $('form'),
    search = $('#search');

    form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    search.addClass('searching').val('');

    setTimeout(function() {
    search.removeClass('searching');
    }, 3600);
    event.currentTarget.submit(); // Com essa linha consigo enviar mas a 
    pesquisa digitada não vai
    });

    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está setando o valor vazio com essa linhda de código:

```
search.addClass('searching').val('');
```

onde o .val('') se refere ao valor da variável referida, ou seja, ('') = vazio.

Answer (score 1):

No seu código está escrito

```
event.currentTarget.submit(); // Com essa linha consigo enviar mas a pesquisa digitada não vai
```

Mas o problema não seria esta outra linha aqui?

```
search.addClass('searching').val('');
```

Você mesmo está passando um valor vazio para o seu input, por isso que na sua request o parâmetro é enviado vazio.

Comment: Realmente, isso resolveu :) Muito obrigado mesmo!